# cupy sum method gives strange value

Tags: python, cupy

I run following code

```
import cupy as cp
x = cp.array([2.0, 3.0])
print(cp.sum(x))
```

Then it says
0.0
as output. Moreover,

```
x = cp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(cp.sum(x))
```

gives 72340172838076673 as output. what's problem? And how can I use sum method correctly?

Comment: This is odd. Can you run another CUDA library without any issues? Please also paste the `cupy.show_config()` output.

Answer (score -1):

```
cupy.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)
```

Returns the sum of an array along given axes.
and the default axis is None, which means it'll return 0 if applied without specifying axis.

Comment: This is not the cause.